# What a safe and easy way to delete a dir in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to delete a directory that may or may not contain files or other directories. Looking in the Ruby docs I found [Dir.rmdir](http://apidock.com/ruby/Dir/rmdir/class) but it won't delete non-empty dir. Is there a convenience method that let's me do this? Or do I need to write a recursive method to examine everything below the directory?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
require 'fileutils'

FileUtils.rm_rf(dir)
```

Comment: Be aware that the docs contain a warning on this: you might expose a vulnerability if you don't pass :secure as an option to rm_rf.

Comment: @BKewl  Reference on that?

Comment: @alex0112: See http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-rm_rf and http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-rm_r

Comment: Just a note, I found that with Windows and Ruby 1.9.3 (at least) `FileUtils.rm_rf` will follow links (symlinks in this case) and delete those files and folders as well. This was found based on creating a symlink with `CreateSymbolicLinkW` and then running `FileUtils.rm_rf` against a parent directory the symlinks are in. Not exactly expected behavior.

Comment: Is there a way to not delete the target of symlinks but only the link file itself?

Comment: Questions go in questions, not comments on nine-year-old answers.

Comment: fiileutils requires >= 2.3.0, which is not on all platforms as standard package available, eg centos 7

Comment: Whatever gave you that idea?  `fileutils.rb` was added to the repo at Tue Mar 26 13:03:04 2002, and the commit is included in the `v1_8_0` tag.  It included `.rm_rf` from the beginning.  That your distro may not include it is something you'll want to take up with them.

Answer (score 3):

A pure Ruby way:

require 'fileutils'

FileUtils.rm_rf("/directory/to/go")

If you need thread safety: (warning, changes working directory)

FileUtils.rm_rf("directory/to/go", :secure=>true)

Comment: fiileutils requires >= 2.3.0, which is not on all platforms as standard package available, eg centos 7

Answer (score 0):

If some looking for answer on @ferventcoder comment -

Just a note, I found that with Windows and Ruby 1.9.3 (at least) FileUtils.rm_rf will follow links (symlinks in this case) and delete those files and folders as well. This was found based on creating a symlink with CreateSymbolicLinkW and then running FileUtils.rm_rf against a parent directory the symlinks are in. Not exactly expected behavior.

– ferventcoder

Safest way is to iterate path and delete it manually.

def rec_del(path):

1. if path is file call FileUtils.rm_rf - it is safe to delete even in windows
2. if dir call Dir.rmdir which will succeed for empty dir and dir symlink. else will get ENOTEMPTY for regular non empty dir.
3. iterate the dir and call rec_del for each item.
4. now call again Dir.rmdir which will succeed

Answer (score -3):

The laziest way is:

```
def delete_all(path)
    `rm -rf "#{path}"`
end
```

Comment: Does not work on Windows. Unnecessarily starts two subprocesses (a shell and `rm` itself). Just returns an error code instead of a potentially more detailed exception message. (You may want to delete this answer, @AnaBetts.)

Comment: At least it works without requiring ruby >= 2.3.0. A similar logic could be implemented for the different os variants needed to be supported